# Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 9.1.0, failed version requirement: <9.0.0

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am new to ionic and try to add androidx library to my ionic cordova project.... When I enable androidx through gradle.properties, it is throwing "err empty response" exception...

Please help me...

Thanks

Comment: Show your code, your android build files (gradle, ...)
Best way to migrate to AndroidX is to do it with Android Studio. Go on tab Refactor --> Migrate to AndroidX --> Do refactor

Comment: Tnx bro... But I did migrate using ur method... But the build again rewriting the gralde.properties and config file...